# UNITY c#NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection

Probably a stupid question, well, I'm specifically stuck and I don't understand why this happened. *DontDestroyOnLoad(_panelManager);* works out and the object is not deleted between scenes, and besides, the message *Panel is initialized* is displayed in the console, that is, I get into this part of the code and I get the *PanelManager2 component* .  but when calling the **open** method from another script, I get a message in the console "Panel is not initialized"
and if I remove the if else check, I get a null reference exception.I haven't really figured out yet how to interact with all this and i will be glad for your hint.

I used debug.log after this

```
line _panelManager = GetComponent<PanelManager2>();
```

and I didn't get null in the console. What is the problem then?

```
public class LoadingScreen : MonoBehaviour, ILoadingScreen
{
    [SerializeField] private PanelManager2 _panelManager;
    private bool _isInitialized;
   

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializePanelManager();
    }

    private void InitializePanelManager()
    {
        _panelManager = GetComponent<PanelManager2>();
        //_panelManager.Init(); //not actual 'Awake' method instead
       DontDestroyOnLoad(_panelManager);
        _isInitialized = true;
        Debug.Log("Panel is initialized");
    }
    
    public void Open()
    { 
        if (_isInitialized)
        {
            _panelManager.OpenPanel<TutorialPanel>();
            Debug.Log("Panel is open");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Panel is not initialized");
        }
    }
}


public class PanelManager2 : PanelManagerBase
{
    
    public void Awake()
    {
        
        CreatePanelsFromSettings();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to apply dependency injection, but I'm not sure if it's happening because of this.

Bootstrap class
. . .

```
private IEnumerator Start()
        {
            var loadingScreen = _sharedContainer.Resolve<ILoadingScreen>();
            
            
            
            loadingScreen.Open();

        }
```

Comment: I presume the `Start` method of your `LoadingScreen` class isn't being called here? I really don't know much about Unity but I vaguely recall that it should be `public IEnumerator Start()`?

Comment: @DavidG No.You're wrong. The start method of the Loading Screen class is called, because if start hadn't worked, I wouldn't have entered the InitializePanelManager method. But I got the corresponding message in the console. the second start method refers to another script in which I call the open method. I use the IEnumerator for coroutine to create delays of several seconds between scene switches, but this is not important here.